# how to write "where in" clause in mysql-wrapper node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

how to write the below query in node js, which uses mysql-wrapper node package

```
SELECT name,Yr FROM table_abc where city IN ('Paris','London','Hyderabad', 'Delhi') ;
```

The querying format for node mysql-wrapper is the below one:

```
conn.query('SELECT * FROM table {{where data}}', {
    data: {
        a: 1,
        b: 'abc'
    }
}, function(err, result){
    console.log(err, result)
});
```

**How to write "where IN" clause . Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you refering to this [mysql-wrapper](https://github.com/kaelzhang/node-mysql-wrapper) ?

Comment: did you try using `city:['Paris','London']` ?

Comment: ya i tried but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you link to the precise module you're using ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql-wrapper

Comment: This is a repository with no star (so probably no user) and almost no code. I'm not sure you should use that.

Comment: the db-mysql package is quite simple to work with imo. have you given it a shot? http://nodejsdb.org/db-mysql/ has some great little example snippets.